# Write a nested IIF function

Tags: sql-server

I'm given this problem

> Task: Business Case:
>
> The accounting department would like to know the current
>   balances for vendors that owe money on their accounts. They would like to
>   categorize vendors who owe over $11,000 as having a Very High debt level, those
>   who owe between $11,000 and over $500 as having a High debt level, those who
>   owe between $500 and over $200 as having a Medium debt level and anyone
>   else as a Low debt level.Write a select statement that returns 3 columns:
>
> ```
>    VendorName
>      BalanceDue: balance due calculated column using the SUM function
>      DebtLevel: nested IIF function that does the following:
>         o Sum of Balances greater than $11,000 = ‘Very High’
>         o Sum of Balances between $11,000 and greater than $500 = ‘High’
>         o Sum of Balances between $500 and greater than $200 = ‘Medium’
>         o Sum of Balances equal to $200 or less = ‘Low’
> ```
>
> Filter the results to only include vendors where a balance is due and sort the 
>   results from the sum of largest balance to smallest.

Comment: And what have you attempted so far?

Comment: You might want to look at using a case ststement.. I think it will be much better..

Comment: Can't it has to be an IIF

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT VendorName
      ,SUM([balance]) AS [BalanceDue]
      ,IIF
        (
            SUM([balance]) => 11000
           ,'Very High debt level'
           ,IIF
           (
                SUM([balance]) >= 500 AND SUM([balance]) < 11000
               ,'High debt level'
               ,IIF
               (
                    SUM([balance]) < 500 AND SUM([balance]) <= 200
                    ,'Medium debt level'
                    ,'Low debt level'
               )
           )
        ) AS [DebtLevel]
FROM [my_table]
GROUP BY VendorName
```